# How can I get all of the graphics to load?

Tags: prison-architect

I bought the standard prison architect game of steam and not all the graphics are loaded.

Did I buy the wrong one? I cant see any of the objects/prisoners/guards etc. Should I download a different version of the game? How can I make all of the graphics appear?

Comment: Have you tried verifying the files in Steam?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you've had a corrupted install. Right click on the game in Steam, select *Properties*, then *Local Files*, and finally *Verify Integrity of Game Cache* at the bottom of the group of buttons you'll see.

If that fails to resolve the issue, right-click on the game again and try opening in safe mode. If you continue to have issues, it would probably be more helpful to report them directly to the developer, as the game is still in Alpha.